# Maximo 7.6.1.2 Create GL Component from integration

Tags: integration, maximo, inbound

I have a requirement which need to create GLComponent value from JSON inbound integration. The problem i face is the external system **will not send** ORGANIZATION(ORGID) value since glcomponents is declare as global value there while in Maximo it is Mandatory.

I am able to populate the value if only one single organization is used. But i might have two or more organization in Maximo, how can i create/populate glcomponents value into all of my organization from the integration?

Thank you for the help.

GL Component value from Chart of account application

[image: GL Component value from Chart of account application]